# iOS 8 local notifications are not displayed in call screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

A strange problem with local notification in call screen with iOS8!

A rapid picture : I'm working on a dualMode(GSM/VoIP) communication application (behind a PABX), with a custom event channel (http chunk channel) which provides us information about a received call.

When a user receives an incoming GSM call and when this call is monitored by the PABX the application also receives (via this event channel) an event with additional information about the call.

Now suppose that:

1. The phone is locked (so application is in background)
2. The phone receives an incoming GSM call --> the "native locked incoming call
   screen" is displayed (those who user has to scroll to hang up)
3. User hang up (by sliding)
4. Now iPhone displays the native "online call service screen" (the screen with mute/keyboard/speaker/... icons)
5. My App (in background) receives an event and programs an immediate local notification.

Now two behaviors:

**Prior to iOS8**

- the local notification is displayed
- when user taps on it, the application is open, **cool !!!**.

**With iOS8.X.X**

- the local notification fires silently : popup not displayed on screen.
- but local notification is available in notification center.  **So bad !!**

**More info**

- Even more strange, when the local notification fires, the font of the top status bar is slightly changed (bigger)!!
- When I leave the call screen my phone is still locked, and my notification is here !! **So bad again !!**
- Of course, I have ask for all permissions for displaying localNotif, all is well configured in notification center...
- When the phone is unlocked --> No problem, my local notifs fires and is displayed.
- I have also try to fire an alarm when my phone displays this "call screen" (via the timer application) --> same behavior as my app, the local notif play its sounds, but notif is not displayed!!)

Seems to be an platform regression no ???

Any help/idea is really welcomed this pb is an application killer for me !!

Thx a lot